# How to get index number of each month as a new column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with date column and valuename column. The dataset is similar to this:

```
df=
datecreated     valuename
2019-08-01        QA
2019-08-02        BS
2019-08-14        BV
2019-08-30        QT
2019-07-04        QA
2019-07-09        QA
2019-07-11        QT
2019-07-17        BV
2019-07-29        QA

df schema= datecreated: timestamp 
           valuename: string
```

I am trying to get an output similar to this:

```
Month         month_count    QA_count BS_count BV_count QT_count B
2019-07         0                    3         0        1          1
2019-08         1                    1         1        1          1
```

I have already getting all columns except month_count column... I would like to get an index number based on my month column.

Comment: Posting pandas answer so you might derive pyspark answer from it `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datecreated', freq='M'))['valuename'].value_counts().unstack(-1, fill_value=0)`

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for the comment, but this return an output without the date column

Comment: That shouldn;t be...Screenshot of the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKMGD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use groupBy and pivot methods of Pyspark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy(F.date_format('datecreated', 'yyyy-MM').alias('month')
                ).pivot('valuename').count().fillna(0)

df2.show()
+-------+---+---+---+---+
|  month| BS| BV| QA| QT|
+-------+---+---+---+---+
|2019-07|  0|  1|  3|  1|
|2019-08|  1|  1|  1|  1|
+-------+---+---+---+---+

df3 = df.groupBy(F.date_format('datecreated', 'yyyy-MM').alias('month')).pivot('valuename').count().fillna(0).withColumn('month_count', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('month')) - 1)
df3.show()
+-------+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|  month| BS| BV| QA| QT|month_count|
+-------+---+---+---+---+-----------+
|2019-07|  0|  1|  3|  1|          0|
|2019-08|  1|  1|  1|  1|          1|
+-------+---+---+---+---+-----------+
```

Comment: I tried using this syntax  but I got an invalid syntax error

Comment: @Mandibajr what syntax error?

Comment: I am using pyspark

Comment: @Mandibajr then what error you got?

Comment: sorry I made an indentation error, it works well.but can I add a count that index each month..like 2019-07 has index 0 ,2019-08 has index 1,2019-09 has index 2..and so on just as updated in the question

Comment: @Mandibajr see edited answer

Comment: that did the job, can you please suggest material for Improving my proficiency in pyspark

Comment: thanks for the assistances ,I would like to optimise the output by having cumulative sum of the BS,BV,QA,QT column

Comment: @Mandibajr use `F.sum(F.col('BS')).over(Window.orderBy('month'))`, and similarly for other columns.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but in a case where I have numerous column like 15 ,I have to run for each of the 15 columns?

Comment: @Mandibajr then use `[F.sum(F.col(i)).over(...) for i in df.columns]`

Comment: I just tried that syntax but got an invalid syntax..

Comment: Comments are not intended for extended discussions. Please open another question for this issue, thank you